# How to interpret Database "Updatable" property/Error (3027). Cannot update. Database or object is read-only

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

One of my users (running Windows 7 64bit) has reported that she gets the following error message when starting my application:

basApplicationTitle.SetStartupProperty on line 410 Error (3027). Cannot update. Database or object is read-only

The offending code is:

```
Private Function SetAppTitle(pstrRpValue As String) As Boolean

390      On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

         Dim dbsDb As DAO.Database
         Dim prp As DAO.Property

400      Set dbsDb = CurrentDb()

405      SetAppTitle = False

         ' Set the Application Title property value.
410      dbsDb.Properties("AppTitle") = pstrRpValue '<= the line that  triggers the error
420      SetAppTitle= True

PROC_EXIT:
430      Set dbsDb = Nothing
440      ProcPop
450      Exit Function

PROC_ERR:
460      Select Case Err.Number
             Case 3270 'Property not found; create it and try again.
470              Set prp = dbsDb.CreateProperty("AppTitle", dbtest, pstrRpValue )
480              dbsDb.Properties.Append prp
490              Resume
500          Case Else
510              SetStartupProperty = False
520              LogError 'Report the error
530      End Select
540      Resume PROC_EXIT
550      Resume

     End Function
```

I'm assuming she hasn't got access to update one of either the backend or frontend database and I need to test for this when opening the frontend and connecting the backend.

Question 1: Does the property currentdb().updatable check both the frontend AND backend or do I need to test independently?

Question 2: Is currentdb().updatable a sufficient test?

Question 2: What guidance can I provide in an error message -- I'm assuming that checking the files for the read-only attribute is one thing. Is there a question of user account privileges? Or locking files? Anything else I need to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CurrentDB.Updatable` will tell you if the front-end is read-only. For the purposes of checking whether or not you can update the Application Title that test should be sufficient.

As for why the front-end might be open as read-only, some possible causes would be:

- The filesystem's "read-only" attribute might be set on the front-end file (as you mentioned).
- The front-end file might be in a folder to which the user has read-only access. For example, a regular user only has read-only access to `%ProgramFiles%` (e.g., "C:\Program Files\...").
- Multiple concurrent users opening the same Access file can force some users to read-only in certain circumstances. However, that should not be an issue for the front-end of a shared Access database application because each user **must** have their own local copy of the front-end file. (That is, multiple concurent users opening the same copy of the front-end file from a shared location is a Very Bad Thing.)

### Edit re: comment

**(1) Testing back-end access:**

To verify that the user can write to the back-end database you could just have your startup code try to perform a test update that doesn't change any data, e.g.,

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
cdb.Execute "UPDATE LinkedTbl SET Field1=Field1 WHERE ID=1", dbFailOnError
```

If the back-end is read-only then you'll get error 3073 "Operation must use an updatable query".

**(2) Front-end access considerations:**

As for machinations to work around the case where the user does not have write access to the front-end, I wouldn't bother. Anything but the most trivial Access application will need to make *some* changes to the (front-end) database object so users really do need write access to the front-end file.

My preferred approach would be to use an installer or a front-end updater that places the front-end file in a location where a regular user can expect to have read/write access, specifically their own file space on their local hard drive (e.g. "C:\Users\Gord...").

Comment: So I'd need to do something like 'Set dbs = opendatabase ("Filename")and then test dbs.updatable to ensure the backend is OK as well? Plus work out some way of updating the application title to include the backend file name if the user doesn't have admin privileges. And check there's nowhere else in the app that the frontend database is written to...

Comment: Thanks. I won't get away with not putting it in %ProgramFiles% so I either need to code a way to update the window title without using the Application Title; or not show the current data file in the application title (which generates its own problems).

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl re: "won't get away with not putting it in %ProgramFiles%" - It's your call I suppose, but IMO the front-end file doesn't really belong there. The Access application itself (full product or runtime) certainly does, but Access front-ends are just *documents* as far as the operating system is concerned, so to do that you may have to fuss about to get your application to run smoothly. :(